# Valid use of Youtube Data v3 API key

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a Spotify API key and a YouTube Data V3 API key that I use in a software program. My software is free to use and open source, and I do not charge for usage. My application/program interacts with users in this way:

- a user provides a Spotify url, playlist, or code
- the item is looked up through Spotify's API service and returns the title and the author, or in the case of a playlist, returns the title and author for each song in the playlist
- the software takes the list of title-artist pairs and uses the YouTube Data V3 API to search for the appropriate YouTube links for each title-artist pair
- the YouTube url for those songs are provided to the user via the software

Is this a valid, legal use of the YouTube Data V3 API?

I have looked through the YouTube API Services Developer Policies at https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies and I have not seen anything that indicates that this usage would be against the policies but wanted to make sure.

Comment: The users that clone my software project are prompted to use their own keys for both services as I do not provide keys with the software.

Comment: I see no legal issues with your usage patterns of the API (disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer though).